# Test controller with rspec - need to stub before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, mocha.js, stub

I have in `User.rb` model:

```
before_save { self.email.downcase! }
```

and I need to stub this method in `users_controller_spec.rb`:

```
User.any_instance.stubs(:before_save_callback_method).returns(true) #doesn't work
User.any_instance.stubs(:valid?).returns(true) #works
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to stub out the before_save callback, rather you can stub out methods called by the callback. You can move the behavior to a method and stub that instead.

```
before_save :downcase_email

def downcase_email
  self.email.downcase!
end
```

Then in your specs:

```
user.stub(:downcase_email).and_return(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mock, it can be done like this

```
describe User
  it "should accept email_downcase before save" do
    user = mock(User)
    user.should_receive(:email_down).and_return(email.downcase) # => use return in case you want to
  end
end
```

thanks

Comment: Thank you, @Paritosh Singh.
Unfortunately it doesn't solve problem. Because problem is an error during post 'create': undefined method `downcase!' for nil:NilClass.
@beef jerky gave the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

do you really need that before_save method? maybe it would be better if you override email=, so the email gets downcased just right after assignment and you have that downcased even before saving the record

```
User < ActiveRecord
  def email=(value)
    write_attribute(:email, value.downcase)
  end
end
```

I don't know if that helps for your test, but sometimes that's better than a before_save callback